# Decomposition products of magnesium ethanoate

Tags: organic-chemistry

What does magnesium ethanoate decompose to? The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_ethanoate) states that one of the products is magnesium oxide. What's the other product? I can come up with some guesses:

- Ethanoic anhydride ($\ce{MgC4H6O4(s) -> C4H6O3(g) + MgO(s)}$)
- Propanone and carbon dioxide ($\ce{MgC4H6O4(s) -> C3H6O(g) + CO2(g) + MgO(s)}$)

Comment: Since calcium acetate (ethanoate) decomposes into propanone, I'd say that it is the case here as well. Also, at least some metal oxides, particularly ThO2, catalyze carboxylic acids' decomposition into ketones. The process seems to be pretty generic, even if requiring quite elevated temperatures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Ok, [here's](http://www.electronicsandbooks.com/eab1/manual/Magazine/T/Thermochimica%20Acta/41_78/0040603184871282.pdf) your answer (*Thermochimica Acta*, 78 (1984) 17-27): It decomposes into the oxide, carbon dioxide and propanone:

$Mg(C_2H_3O_2)_{2(s)} \rightarrow MgO_{(s)} + CO_{2(g)} + CH_3COCH_{3(g)}$

PRE-EDIT:

The [Russian Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) favors the second reaction. [This](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2010/jm/c0jm01261k#!divAbstract) seems to support the idea.

[This site](http://chemister.ru/Database/properties.php?dbid=1&id=3897) mentions magnesium carbonate and propane-2-one as products, but this seems to be questionable, given the other sources.